# How to pass inputs to Java Selenium tests when triggered via a web endpoint?

Tags: java, selenium, servlets, junit, testng

I seek to find a highly scalable and flexible solution for kicking off Selenium tests from a remote machine, preferably via a web-based endpoint, where I can pass some data through to my tests.

I've tried using both jUnitEE and TestNGEE - plus a ServletFilter - trying to get what I want but can't quite hit all my requirements so I can't help but think that I'm trying to go about it completely the wrong way...someone has to have solved this before...I just can't figure out how...

What I'd like to have happen:

1. Someone wanting to execute a java Selenium test navigates to a webpage of mine. Potentially this is a jUnitEE or TestNGEE servlet, perhaps it's something else.
2. User selects a Selenium test to run from a list of available tests, plus a couple of values from form elements on the page. Let's say that it's 2 string values - one for *environment* and one for *username*.
3. User presses the *Run Test* button.
4. The server takes the selected test and starts its execution, providing it with the *environment* and the *username* values specified by the user.

Additional requirements:

- All activities should be thread safe. Data should not get criss-crossed between tests, even when multiple users initiate the same test at the same time.

Notes:

- While I'd be happy to have this working even with just one parameter, the hope is that the user would be able to pass a list of any number of arbitrary key/value pairs which are then made available to the executed test, potentially even a csv or other type of data file, or a web endpoint from which to retrieve the data.

Example:

1. User hits the endpoint: http://testLauncherUI.mySite.com/myServlet?test=com.mySite.selenium.flow1&environment=testEnvironment1.mySite.com&username=userNumber1&otherRandomKey=randomValue
2. testLauncher's myServlet triggers the contained test matching *com.mySite.selenium.flow1* and that test in turn navigates to 'http://**testEnvironment1.mySite.com**', and proceeds to enter the 'userNumber1' text into the input box.
3. A second user can hit the same servlet while the prior test is still executing, but with different (or same) params: http://testLauncherUI.mySite.com/myServlet?test=com.mySite.selenium.flow1&environment=testEnvironment2.mySite.com&username=userNumber1&otherRandomKey=randomValue
4. testLauncher's myServlet kicks off another thread, running the same test, but against the specified site: 'http://**testEnvironment2.mySite.com**', and proceeds to enter the 'userNumber1' text into the input box.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't be a lot more easier for you to just expose this behavior via a build tool such as Jenkins for e.g., ? Instead of exposing your users to your custom page, you could just expose them to a build job in Jenkins and get it done no ?

Comment: Thank you for the input, Krishnan. I'm unable to use jenkins for governance reasons. My build tool would require custom changes that are outside of my scope. I have almost full reign on the 'testing' implementations, but the build system falls outside of this.

Comment: John, here's a basic problem with your servlet approach. Each of your servlets would basically be spinning off new Threads within which your actual test would get executed. So if the spinning off causes the servlet to stall, then eventually you may run into situations wherein all your threads are occupied and thus it effectively brings down your web app.

Comment: So here's what you can do.. Have all of your tests basically populate an internal queue in your web app which tracks all such "test job" requests. You can have a separate thread which polls the queue and then spawns tests. This would be thread safe (You just need to trust the user that he's going to give you thread-safe credentials else one login could cause the other to log out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up dropping JUnitEE altogether. Life is now better. My stack that now makes this possible is: GitLab, GitLabCI (w/Docker), Gradle, Junit/TestNG

- I'm now storing my code in GitLab (Enterprise) and using Gradle as a build system. Doing so allows for this:
  The included GitLabCI to be configured to host a URL that can trigger a GitLab pipeline. Each GitLab pipeline runs in a docker container.
- My GitLabCI config is setup to execute a gradle command when this trigger (URL) is POSTed to. The trigger URL can contain a variable number of custom variables which are turned into Environment Variables by GitLab.
- My project is now a Gradle project so when my GitLab trigger is POSTed to, I'm using Gradle's filters to specify which tests to execute (e.g. `$ ./gradlew test my-test-subproj::test System.getenv( 'TARGETED_TESTS' )).
- I POST the URL for my tests (e.g. `http://myGitLab.com/my-project/trigger?TARGETED_TESTS=com.myapp.feature1.tests`), and a docker container spins up from GitLabCI to run the matching ones. Of course, with this approach, I can set whatever variables that I need to and they can be read in at any level - GitLabCI, Gradle, or the test/test-framework itself.

This approach seems highly flexible and robust enough to do what I need it to, leaving each of my many teams to configure and handle the project to their specific needs without being overly prescriptive.